# How to set colorspace in iText

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I have problem with drawing images in PDF using iText.
iText is creating Black/gray in PNG images (between transparent and non-transparent area in image).

I am not setting this border.
What I found is that colorspace is CMYK, instead RGB. So my question is how can I force RGB colorspace in iText on image?

Images with no transparency are printed fine.